# Error "SQLException: El flujo ya se ha cerrado" al leer un campo de tipo LONG

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-11g, jdbc

Realizo la siguiente petición desde Java con JDBC a `user_tab_columns`:

```sql
SELECT
     column_name,
     data_type,
     nullable,
     data_default,
     char_length,
     char_used
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE table_name = 'mi_tabla'
ORDER BY column_id;
```

Ejemplo de tabla a usar:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."CW_CONTADORES" ( 
"ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
"SUBTIPO" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE) DEFAULT 'coche',
"ZONA" NUMBER DEFAULT -1)
```

Recorro con un while los registros y cuando la columna `data_default` es `-1` me lanza el error:

> java.sql.SQLException: El flujo ya se ha cerrado.

Código:

```
ResultSet resultColumns = stm.executeQuery(query);
while(resultColumns.next())
{
    col_default = resultColumns.getString("data_default") == null ? "" : " DEFAULT " + resultColumns.getString("data_default");
    //trato los datos
}
```

¿Alguien me puede iluminar si hay alguna idea que no sea un try/catch del problema que tengo?

Comment: Por favor, copia el código en que haces la consulta y recuperas los valores.

Comment: **Siempre** incluye un [mcve] para este tipo de preguntas.

Comment: ¿Que tipo de dato es `data_default`?

Comment: `data_default` es una columna de user_tab_columns propia de oracle de la que se pueden obtener las columnas de una tabla.

Comment: Data_default es de tipo Long, ve cambiando eso a ver, que con el poco código que has copiado es difícil ver nada.

Comment: `data_default` se que es de tipo Long y ya lo intente sin exito. Más código no se que necesitas más.

1º Obtengo un ResultSet de la petición SQL.

2º Leo los registros devueltos con un while(result.next()).

3º Obtengo las columnas que necesito pero con `data_default` = -1 no hay manera

Comment: tienes que obtener la data como stream cuando el dato es LONG (tipo de dato que ORACLE recomienda no usar), revisa el ejemplo
[Revisa este enlace ](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/jstreams.htm#i1014085)

Comment: ¿Seguro que el código que incluistes es el que reproduce tu error? ¿Es normal que tengas 2 diferentes result sets: `resultColumns` y `result`? Por favor, una vez mas te animo a repasar el enlace [mcve]. No es complicado, pero tienes que ayudarnos a reproducir tu error, lo que no has hecho todavía. Tengo una buena idea de la causa y solución, pero primero quiero confirmar el error, lo que no puedo hacer todavía con la información disponible.

Comment: "`data_default` se que es de tipo `Long`" es probable que tú sí lo sepas, pero nosotros no, por ello la pregunta de @cnbandicoot. Ahora bien, me parece que el código que provees no brinda el error que indicas. Lo más probable es que estés ejecutando otro query dentro de tu ciclo `while` y almacenes el resultado en la misma variable `ResultSet resultColumns` por "ahorro de variables". De ser así, apoyo a sstan y te recomiendo que brindes el [mcve] para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Hola Luiggi, dentro del while solo leo el resultset, ni más ni menos. Obtengo otros registros perfectamente pero cuando intenta leer del registro `"ZONA" NUMBER DEFAULT -1` el campo data_default me da ese error. Corrijo la linea exacta que no había puesto el if. Y si sirve de ayuda en `expressions` he puesto la variable y me sale el valor de -1 pero si la vuelvo a poner otra vez en el `expressions` me da error, que demonios le pasa a Java 8???

Comment: Si no añades el código completo va a ser difícil que te ayudemos.

Comment: Completo? Estoy dando la definición de una tabla, el select que realizo en el ResultSet y la lectura de esa columna. Que más hace falta?

Comment: Si es de tipo `Long` como dice @LuiggiMendoza, no deberías utilizar `getString`

Comment: Es verdad que esta definido como `Long` https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm pero no puedo obtener una cadena de texto con un `Long` y además el único problema lo tengo cuando la variable es `-1`

Comment: El error que indicas se da bajo unas condiciones que no se producen en el código que has copiado, de ahí la petición de más código. En la parte que no has añadido tiene que estar el origen del error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como los tipos `LONG` y `LONG RAW` están básicamente obsoletos, el leer esos valores correctamente requiere mucho cuidado. El problema es que, aunque no sea aparente a primera vista, cuando una consulta incluye columnas de ese tipo, Oracle abre un *stream* o *flujo* especial para esos tipos. Pero para poder leerlos sin problemas, debes asegurarte de 2 cosas:

1. Que leas las columnas `LONG`/`LONG RAW` en tu bucle *antes* de leer las demás columnas.
2. Que leas las columnas `LONG`/`LONG RAW` *una sola vez* en el bucle.

En cuanto al primer punto, según el código que has compartido, no parece ser el problema. Pero por la forma cómo has ido modificando el código en tu pregunta y cómo aún no pareces tener claro [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), no me sorprendería si el código aún no corresponde a la realidad.

Pero, por lo menos en cuanto al segundo punto, con tu última edición queda claro que hay un problema. Estás leyendo la columna `data_default` 2 veces, lo que no puedes hacer. Cuándo el valor de la columna `data_default` no es `null`, la segunda lectura es la que te da error, porque el *flujo* ya quedó cerrado después de la primera lectura.

La solución es de leer el valor una vez y asignarlo a una variable para evitar una segunda lectura:

```
ResultSet resultColumns = stm.executeQuery(query);
while(resultColumns.next())
{
    String col_default = resultColumns.getString("data_default");
    col_default = col_default == null ? "" : " DEFAULT " + col_default;
    //trato los datos después...
}
```

Si esto no soluciona el problema, entonces lo más probable es que el código en la pregunta todavía no refleja lo que tienes en realidad. Para recibir respuestas acertadas a este tipo de preguntas, y evitar darle vueltas al asunto de forma innecesaria, la clave siempre reside en [crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Si no has leído el enlace todavía, por favor hazlo. Así te ayudas a ti mismo y a nosotros también.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias mi problema era por intentarlo leer dos veces y gracias por la explicación de `LONG` y `LONG RAW`.